# How to post variables to SceneDelegate with helping notification center?

Tags: swift, notifications, uikit

I want to realise check user log in or doesn't by using notification center.
I write a function for user log in. Getting access and refresh tokens is new notification:

```
    func loginUserAuth(data: UserLoginData, completion: @escaping (Result<Any, Error>) -> Void) {
        AF.request("",
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: data,
                   encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseDecodable(of: LoginResponse.self) { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            
            guard let loginResponse = response.value else {
                debugPrint("no data on login")
                return
            }
            
            let keychain = Keychain(server: "", protocolType: .https)
            keychain["access"] = loginResponse.tokens.access
            keychain["refresh"] = loginResponse.tokens.refresh
            
            // POST notification here
            let UserLoggedIn = NotificationCenter.default
            UserLoggedIn.post(name: Notification.Name("UserLoggedIn"), object: nil)**
        }
    }
```

And I need to send in SceneDelegate notifications. But how?

```
 let UserLoggedIn = NotificationCenter.default
        func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {
            accessToken = keychain["access"]
            refreshToken = keychain["refresh"]

        }
        
        let gettingNotification = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
        
        if (gettingNotification) {
            window?.rootViewController = MainTabBarController()
        }
        else
        {
            window?.rootViewController = LoginViewController()
        }
```

I am lost hot to send notification to SceneDelegate.